# jQuery scrollTo Plugin Flicker on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, scrollto

I am using the jQuery plugin, scrollTo, to navigate through my webpage. When I click on the button, there seems to be a quick flicker and then resumes to continue scrolling normally. I saw other solutions where they call the preventDefault() method, but I don't know how I would implement it in my case. Here is my method that is called when a link is clicked.

```
function btn_Pressed(goTo){
    $(goTo).ScrollTo({
    duration: 1200
    });
}
```

It is a generic method that will scroll to whatever anchor is passed as an argument. What am I doing wrong. THIS FLICKER IS SO UGLY!

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution, however, I don't know if it is the most efficient one. I made a function that handles each button click so I could explicitly call and handle each scroll all while calling preventDefault(). Here is a sample...

```
$(function(){
$("#btn_home").click(function(e) {
            $('#myAffix').ScrollTo({
                duration: 1200,

                });
            e.preventDefault();
});
$("#aboutUs").click(function(e) {
            $('#anchorOne').ScrollTo({
                duration: 1200,

                });
            e.preventDefault();
});
$("#btn_home").click(function(e) {
            $('#myAffix').ScrollTo({
                duration: 1200,

                });
            e.preventDefault();
   });

});
```

Comment: This is not very DRY code. You just need to find where you are calling the btn_Pressed function from and pass the event as a second argument to that function. Then you can use preventDefault() as you do in your answer and still use one function to handle all clicks.

Comment: @boszlo hope you are still an active user. Looking back at all my old Stack Overflow questions and shaking my head... this is not to say that I am an expert now by any means. But crazy how much things change. Maybe walking away for a few minutes could have solved the problem at the time....